# How can I decipher the value of the WMI object class, NdisMacOptions?

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query, duplex

I want to determine the duplex of a system using powershell; and the only solution I've found is that you can get the setting by querying the MSNdis_macOptions WMI class, and the NdisMacOptions property is equal to the duplex setting. This is what I'm currently using to get the active interface's value:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object { $_.NetEnabled -eq $True } | ForEach-Object{ Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -class MSNdis_macOptions -filter "InstanceName='$($_.Name)'" }).NdisMacOptions
```

The value I'm getting is 717, which I believe is Full Duplex; but I don't have anything to compare it to. Searching on Google, I've found that most people do not know the meaning of this number. If anyone can point me in the right direction to get the possible values for NdisMacOptions, or what they mean, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the possible values for the `NdisMacOptions` property in the `wmicore.mof`  file (which is part of the [WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513)). This property represents a bitmask that defines optional properties of the underlying driver or its NIC.

```
//  This is an inclusive OR of the following types:

 NDIS_MAC_OPTION_COPY_LOOKAHEAD_DATA     0x00000001
 NDIS_MAC_OPTION_RECEIVE_SERIALIZED      0x00000002
 NDIS_MAC_OPTION_TRANSFERS_NOT_PEND      0x00000004
 NDIS_MAC_OPTION_NO_LOOPBACK             0x00000008
 NDIS_MAC_OPTION_FULL_DUPLEX             0x00000010
 NDIS_MAC_OPTION_EOTX_INDICATION         0x00000020
 NDIS_MAC_OPTION_RESERVED                0x80000000
```

or you can check the `ntddndis.h` file which is part of the [`NDIS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#define NDIS_MAC_OPTION_COPY_LOOKAHEAD_DATA 0x00000001
#define NDIS_MAC_OPTION_RECEIVE_SERIALIZED  0x00000002
#define NDIS_MAC_OPTION_TRANSFERS_NOT_PEND  0x00000004
#define NDIS_MAC_OPTION_NO_LOOPBACK         0x00000008
#define NDIS_MAC_OPTION_FULL_DUPLEX         0x00000010
#define NDIS_MAC_OPTION_RESERVED            0x80000000
```